# Why does my Laravel Voyager admin redirect back to login page after successful login

Tags: php, laravel-5, voyager

The website that has been turned over to me was created in Laravel. Voyager admin is used for updating the contents. I am not yet familiar with Voyager.

I just noticed that upon entry of valid username and password, Voyager admin redirects back to the login page. I have no idea yet where to go to and what codes to check. Is there any config for Voyager admin for me to update?

Comment: Never used voyager, but sounds like it could be an issue with the session storage. Check you config for how sessions are stored (db/disk) etc. and that it is writable etc.

Comment: Hi, on localhost, the Voyager admin is working, but on deployment, the problem occurs. The website is deployed on Amazon Cloud instance.

Comment: @JaimeDolorjr. check `/storage/logs/laravel.log` probably you might see some error, try to fix them.

Answer (score 2):

Many probable causes here.  In my experience, when that happens:

- It may be the user you are logging in with has an admin role (or admin access) on your localhost but does not have "Browser Admin" permissions in your production database. If there is another admin account, use that and check if the user's role has "Browse Admin" permissions.
- If the user is supposed to be an admin, SSH into your server [and grant them the privilege](https://voyager.readme.io/docs/installation) with `php artisan voyager:admin your@email.com`, replacing that email there with the correct one.
- Account does not exist, so create it with `php artisan voyager:admin your@email.com --create`.

Comment: php artisan voyager:admin your@email.com --create works for me

Answer (score 1):

There is a **voyager.php** file for the configuration options of Voyager.

The Voyager config file is present at below location :

```
Laravel/config/voyager.php
```

For more info please refer the documentation :

[Voyager Documentation for config](https://voyager.readme.io/docs/configurations)